# Make a new column based on other columns id values - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

How can i make new columns based on another columns id values?

The data look like this.

```
value       id
551        54089
12         54089
99         54089
55         73516
123        73516
431        73516
742        74237
444        74237
234        74237
```

I want the dataset to look like this.

```
         v1     v2    v3
54089   551     12    99
73516   55      123   431
74237   742     444   234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than 3 values you can create a little helper, that adapts to the size of your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#Dummy Dataframe
 np.random.seed(2016)
 df = pd.DataFrame({'id': 
[54089, 54089, 54089, 73516, 73516, 73516, 73516, 74237, 74237,74237],
                    'value': np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)})
#Create group
grp = df.groupby('id')

#Create helper column 
 df['ID_Count'] = grp['value'].cumcount() + 1

 #Pivot dataframe using helper column and add 'value' column to pivoted output.
 df_out = df.pivot('id','ID_Count','value').add_prefix('v')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` with `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.tolist(), 
                                                         index=['v1', 'v2', 'v3']))\
                              .unstack()
# or

df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), 
                                                       index=['v1', 'v2', 'v3']).T)

print(df)
        v1   v2   v3
id                  
54089  551   12   99
73516   55  123  431
74237  742  444  234
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the excellent answers already provided :

```
(df.astype({'value':str})
 .groupby('id')
 .agg(','.join)
 .value.str.split(',',expand=True)
 .set_axis(['v1','v2','v3'],axis=1)
 .astype(int)
)

        v1  v2  v3
id          
54089   551 12  99
73516   55  123 431
74237   742 444 234
```